# How to show results from the last search?

Tags: search

I have this senario:A user makes a search (using search api solr).
After some days he returns to the site and in the front page appear results related to the last search he made.
How can I accomplish that with Search api?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could try [Search API Saved Searches Module](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_saved_searches)

> This module offers users the ability to save searches executed with
>   the Search API module and be notified of new results. Notifications
>   are done via mails with token-replacement, their frequency can be
>   configured both by admins and/or users and saved searches can also be
>   created without first executing the search.
>
> Facet, Views or other filters set for the search will also be included
>   in a saved search, thus reflecting exactly the same search results as
>   displayed.